# Probability of two random nucleotide strings of length $n$ sharing a substring of length $k$, hints?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Fix $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$, $n$ denoting the string length, $k$ denoting the substring length. Consider the alphabet $\Sigma = \{A, C, T, G\}$ and the language $L$ consisting of all the strings of length $n$ on this alphabet. Consider two strings $s_a$ and $s_b$ uniformly sampled from $L$. What is the probability that $s_a$ and $s_b$ share a common substring of length $k$?

This arose from a research problem in bioinformatics. I don't really need exact answers (so approximations are more than fine). I am mainly seeking for hints; I have tried defining events (fixing $k = 3$ in this example) such as $ATG_{1a}$ denoting the event that the substring $ATG$ occurs at position $1$ in $s_a$. The problem is that $ATG_{2a}$ and $ATG_{1a}$ are not independent events, leading to conditional probabilities that I fear is overcomplicating the problem.

Any approximation or any easier way to deal with this probability?

Comment: How do you define such a $k$-substring. Does it have to be consecutive letters from the $n$-string so for instance the first $k$ letters, or can it be any subsequence of length $k$ combined to a $k$-string by removing the other $(n-k)$ letters? I ask because such subsequences play a role in genetics where there is a nice algorithm for finding the longest common subsequence.

Comment: It appears from your example that you actually mean substring rather than subsequence, right?

Comment: This looks difficult. See for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/probability-of-a-subsequence-occurring-simultaneously-in-two-longer-sequences

Comment: @leonbloy: It sure does!

Comment: @String I am using substring as in they have to be consecutive. This actually came out of exploring kmer profiling.